# AndroidStudio убийца памяти

Tags: java, ubuntu, android-studio, memory

По-моему, довольно таки насущный вопрос. Программирую в Android Studio на ОС Ubuntu(16.04). Ноутбук довольно таки неплохой, под неплохим я имею в виду (8gb RAM,i5-5gn 2.2ghz, правда без SSD).

Эммулятор как таковой запускаю редко, в принципе всё на девайсе прогоняю. Зайдя в диспетчер задач, вижу что две `java` забирают 3.8gb + сама `студия` ещё 1.2gb, остальные задачи в сумме не набирают и 1gb. Ну пускай даже в сумме 6gb затраченно. Но ради интереса вбив в терминал free -m, вижу картинку немного другую:

Mem: total:7898; used:7113; free:262; shared:129; buff/cache:522; available:291

Swap: total:11761; used:3341; free:8420.

Картина не очень веселая, быть может даже местами непонятная.

А вопрос следующий: как *быть может* возможно сократить такое огромное кол-во потребляемой оперативной памяти или хотя бы приравнять её к равной нагрузке в диспетчере задач.

P.S. Как наблюдение, у коллеги по работе, работающим над тем же проектом что и я, студия потребляет 5.72gb, правда на MacOS.

Comment: В конфигах студии и грэдла можно указать максимальный объем памяти, выделяемый на эти программы (смотрите про оптимизацию Android studio). Насколько я знаю, системы Linux, в отличии от Windows, не экономят оперативную память, а наоборот, стараются использовать ее всю для повышения производительности. Такое выделение памяти создает вам проблемы для работы других программ или вам просто хочется, чтобы половина памяти была пустой и простаивала, когда для работы студии дополнительный ресурс по ram никогда не лишний.

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от размера проекта, чем больше проект, чем больше открыто файлов в реальном времени, тем больше идет потребление ОЗУ. У меня на Mac OS студия потребляет в среднем 1гб, но у меня и проекта небольшие, хотя когда я открывал какой-то жирующий open-source проект показатель ОЗУ был как раз таки на 3-4гб.